# Kml File show Elevation profile

Tags: javascript

I have found the following example:

http://gmaps-samples-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/elevation/elevation-profile.html

and I have this kml File:

https://maps.google.at/maps/ms?authuser=0&vps=2&hl=de&ie=UTF8&msa=0&output=kml&msid=211992892838821122253.0004bd00127898df568d9

Now I don't know how to bring the kml file and the example together.
The example includes the path data hard coded.

It would be great if someone could help me.
Thanks a lot
Max

Comment: I have same problem, I thinks you must parse Kml before pass data of path to Google Maps Api

Answer (score 1):

Let me see if I got this right. You have a KML file and you want to create an elevation profile for it?
If so, why don't you use [GPS Visualizer](http://www.gpsvisualizer.com/profile_input) ?